# Save array of ActiveRecord objects?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my view I do:

```
<table border="1">
 <tr>
    <th>Question</th>
    <th>Counter</th>
    <th>Lastsent</th>
    <th>Email</th>
  </tr>
<% @email_stats.each do |email_stat| %>
<% post = Post.find(email_stat.postId) %>
  <% if post.posttype == 'Question' %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= post.question %></td>
    <td><%=  email_stat.counter%></td>
    <td><%= email_stat.lastsent %></t>
    <td><%=  text_field_tag 'email', email_stat.email%></td>
  </tr>
  <%  end %>
 </table>
```

This is what I have: For some objects, the email will be "blank" so I want to display all the records in the table  and allow the moderator to enter an email and on click on save store it.

I used `form_for` but it's used to save only a single object.

What is the best way to send an array back to the server for saving?

Comment: email_state.postId looks like something is wrong here. It should be `post_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected behavior can be achieved by using form_tag instead of form_for. Example

```
<%= form_tag :url => , :html => {:id=> , :method => , :class => ""} do %>
  <% text_field_tag <id>, <default_value>, :name=>"post[question]" %>
  <% text_field_tag <id>, <default_value>, :name=>"email_stat[counter]" %>
  <% text_field_tag <id>, <default_value>, :name=>"email_stat[last_sent]" %>
  <% text_field_tag <id>, <default_value>, :name=>"email_stat[email]" %>
  <%= submit_tag 'save' %>
<% end %>
```

the params will then nicely be grouped in a hash like

```
{'post' => {'question' => 'xxx' }, 'email_stat' => {'counter' => 'xxx' , 'last_sent' =>  'xxx', 'email' => 'xxx'}}
```

which you can parse to update both the models. All you need to do is name the text_field properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use ajax so that serialize the data from the table using jquery and post the data back to the server side. So you can save the array.